# Save profiles / files Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I want to uninstall Alfresco and re-install again, but I don't want to loose the accounts created in Alfresco and the other things. Is there any way to save this ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's assume that by re-installing you mean you want to start with a clean alfresco WAR and share WAR. If so, you can just shut down, remove the alfresco and share directories, then place the clean WARs in the $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps directory. If you had any AMPs deployed, use MMT to re-install those. Then, restart Tomcat. The content is in the content store directory and the metadata is in the database, so you can start over with fresh WARs without losing any data.

If you mean you want to delete everything in $ALFRESCO_HOME but you want to save your data, the easiest thing to do is to dump your database and tar up your content store. Then you can completely blow away your installation, and after reinstalling, you can load your database and un-tar your content store.

If you are trying to blow away some, but not all of your data, you'll have to export what you want to keep. You might go look at the docs on ACP files as one possible approach. Or you could use something like CMIS to write an exporter.

For users, specifically, it is often helpful to use an LDAP directory instead of managing them in Alfresco directly. That way you can completely start over and Alfresco will simply synchronize your users from LDAP.

If you don't want to use LDAP an alternative is to have a simple CSV file with user account data. After starting your repository for the first time you can re-import your users from the CSV file.